# Printing directly from read() in Python adds an extra newline

Tags: python, file-io

I've got a Python script that prints out a file to the shell:

```
print open(lPath).read()
```

If I pass in the path to a file with the following contents (no brackets, they're just here so newlines are visible):

```
> One
> Two
>
```

I get the following output:

```
> One
> Two
> 
>
```

Where's that extra newline coming from? I'm running the script with bash on an Ubuntu system.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
print open(lPath).read(),  # notice the comma at the end.
```

`print` adds a newline. If you end the `print` statement with a comma, it'll add a space instead.

You can use

```
import sys
sys.stdout.write(open(lPath).read())
```

If you don't need any of the special features of `print`.

If you switch to Python 3, or use `from __future__ import print_function` on Python 2.6+, you can use the `end` argument to stop the `print` function from adding a newline.

```
print(open(lPath).read(), end='')
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you should write:

```
print open(lPath).read(),
```

(notice trailing comma at the end).

This will prevent `print` from placing a new-line at the end of its output.